How to conditionally render the relationships in rails. I am using jsonapi-rb for serialization
I have tried using procs for conditionally rendering the relationships but it does not work. What can I  do to render the relationships conditionally
class ProductSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer

  attributes :name, :price, :product_type

  belongs_to :category, if: Proc.new { |record, params| record.trending? }
  has_many :reviews
end

this is what I expect to get in response based on the code.
expected output:
{
    "data": {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "products",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Test products",
            "product_type": "something",
            "price": "12345"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "reviews": {
                "data": []
            }
        }
    },
    "included": [],
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    }
}

this is what I actually got
actual output:
{
    "data": {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "products",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Test products",
            "product_type": "something",
            "price": "12345"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "category": {
                "meta": {
                        "included": false
                    }
            },
            "reviews": {
                "data": []
            }
        }
    },
    "included": [],
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    }
}


Can you please provide the current output and the anticipated output?

Post your controller logic that calls the serializer and make sure you're adding the params correctly.  Also, instead of calling trending? try forwarding a boolean as a param

I have updated the question to include the expected and actual response output
